# Inject DLL to process in session 0 by NtCreateThreadEx

Tags: c++, winapi

I have written DLL injector, to inject i use NtCreateThread to create remote thread into remote process
I work on 64 bit OS - Windows 7
To comiple i use
32 bit - g++ (tdm-2) 4.8.1
64 bit - g++ (tdm64-1) 5.1.0

Problem concerns 64 bit verion of my injector
I have 2 problems
1)
OK. My injector sometimes work and sometimes not work.
I dont know what is reason.

This is problematic line
funcNtCreateThreadEx( &hRemoteThread,GENERIC_EXECUTE, NULL, hProcess, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)lpBaseAddress, lpSpace, FALSE, NULL, NULL, NULL, (LPVOID)ntbuffer );

When i call function NtCreateThreadEx and in last argument is pointer to NtCreateThreadExBuffer, it not work.

```
funcNtCreateThreadEx( &hRemoteThread,GENERIC_EXECUTE /*GENERIC_ALL 0x1FFFFF/*Może tu jest błąd*/, NULL, hProcess, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)lpBaseAddress, lpSpace, FALSE, NULL, NULL, NULL, **ntbuffer** );
```

When i give in last parametr NULL it works and I DONT KNOW WHY.

```
funcNtCreateThreadEx( &hRemoteThread,GENERIC_EXECUTE /*GENERIC_ALL 0x1FFFFF/*Może tu jest błąd*/, NULL, hProcess, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)lpBaseAddress, lpSpace, FALSE, NULL, NULL, NULL, **NULL** );
```

Any idea?

2)
I use NtCreateThreadEx because i want inject code to SYSTEM PROCESS (like csrss.exe) because i like BSoD :).
Unfortunately, my injector can inject code ONLY to process in this same session.
Reason is ?Session Separation? (implemented on Vista and every later OS)
It is rise why i cannot use CreateRemoteThread
I have thought when i use NtCreateThreadEx separation of sessions is not a problem.
I try inject DLL to process in sesion 0.

I tried reduce the privileges
I replaced:

```
HProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, PID);
```

on

```
HProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD, FALSE, PID);
```

etc. but it not work.
Can you tell me why NtCreateThreadEx() works in admin mode, but not in standard mode ? 
Maby i should use other undocumented functions (like NtCreateThreadEx) for example NtOpenProcess to get handle to process with all access?

I need any idea what i should doing. Please help me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

struct NtCreateThreadExBuffer;
HANDLE NtCreateThreadEx(HANDLE hProcess,LPVOID lpBaseAddress,    LPVOID lpSpace);
BOOL EnableDebugPrivilege();

int main()
{
    int PIDOfProcess = 0;
    std::string pathToDLL = "dll64.dll\0";  ///find DLL in local directory
    DWORD PID        = (DWORD)PIDOfProcess; ///PID
    HANDLE HProcess  = NULL;                ///Handle to process
    LPVOID LibAddr   = NULL;                ///Address of procedure 'LoadLibraryA'
    LPVOID DllAdr    = NULL;                ///Address of memory in other process
    HANDLE hThread   = NULL;                ///Handle to remote thread
    int WirteStatus  = 0;                   ///Status of writing to memory of other process

    std::cout << "Get PID of process" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> PIDOfProcess;
    PID = (DWORD)PIDOfProcess;

    if(EnableDebugPrivilege() == true)
    {
        std::cout << "Debug privilege was enabled with status: "<< GetLastError() << "      [OK]" << std::endl;
    }else std::cout << "Debug privilege was not enabled: "<< GetLastError() << "                 [FAILED]" << std::endl;

/*
NtOpenProcess(
  OUT PHANDLE             ProcessHandle,
  IN ACCESS_MASK          AccessMask,
  IN POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES   ObjectAttributes,
  IN PCLIENT_ID           ClientId );*/
   /// NtOpenProcess();
    HProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD, FALSE, PID);
    if(HProcess == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Could not find process: "<< GetLastError() << "                           [FAILED]" << std::endl;
        system("pause");
        return GetLastError();
    }   std::cout << "Process opened:                                    [OK]" << std::endl;

    DllAdr = (LPVOID)VirtualAllocEx(HProcess, NULL, pathToDLL.size() +1, MEM_RESERVE|MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    if(DllAdr == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Cannot allocate memory in remote process: "<< GetLastError() << "     [FAILED]" << std::endl;
        system("pause");
        return GetLastError();
    }   std::cout << "Region of memory in remote process allocated:      [OK]" << std::endl;

    WirteStatus = WriteProcessMemory(HProcess, (LPVOID)DllAdr, pathToDLL.c_str() ,pathToDLL.size()+1, NULL);
    if(WirteStatus == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Could not write to process's address space: "<< GetLastError() << "   [FAILED]" << std::endl;
        system("pause");
        return GetLastError();
    }   std::cout << "A memory has written name of DLL:                  [OK]" << std::endl;

    LibAddr = (LPVOID)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");
    if(LibAddr == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Unable to locate LoadLibraryA: "<< GetLastError() << "                [FAILED]" << std::endl;
        system("pause");
        return GetLastError();
    }   std::cout << "A address of procedure LoadLibraryA has found      [OK]" << std::endl;


    hThread = NtCreateThreadEx(HProcess,LibAddr,DllAdr);

    if(hThread == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Could not create remote thread on process: "<< GetLastError() << "    [FAILED]" << std::endl;
        system("pause");
        return GetLastError();
    }
    system("pause");
}
struct NtCreateThreadExBuffer///This information is derived based on reverse engineering work.
{
     ULONG Size;
     ULONG Unknown1;
     ULONG Unknown2;
     PULONG Unknown3;
     ULONG Unknown4;
     ULONG Unknown5;
     ULONG Unknown6;
     PULONG Unknown7;
     ULONG Unknown8;
};
HANDLE NtCreateThreadEx(HANDLE hProcess,LPVOID lpBaseAddress,LPVOID lpSpace)
{
    ///The prototype of NtCreateThreadEx from undocumented.ntinternals.com
    ///typ_zwracanej_wartości (__konwencja_wywolania*nazwa_wskaźnika)(typ1 argument1, typ2 argument2);
    /* 2OOO, 11 November http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/
    NTSYSAPI NTSTATUS NTAPI NtCreateThread(
    OUT PHANDLE             ThreadHandle,
    IN ACCESS_MASK          DesiredAccess,
    IN POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES   ObjectAttributes OPTIONAL,
    IN HANDLE               ProcessHandle,
    OUT PCLIENT_ID          ClientId,
    IN PCONTEXT             ThreadContext,
    IN PINITIAL_TEB         InitialTeb,
    IN BOOLEAN              CreateSuspended );*/
    typedef LONG64 (WINAPI * functypeNtCreateThreadEx)(
         PHANDLE                 ThreadHandle,      ///Handle to thread which will be created                           /// OUT
         ACCESS_MASK             DesiredAccess,     ///possible: GENERIC_WRITE GENERIC_READ GENERIC_EXECUTE GENERIC_ALL//// IN
         LPVOID                  ObjectAttributes,                                                                      /// IN,OPTIONAL
         HANDLE                  ProcessHandle,     ///Handle to our process                                            /// IN
         LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE  lpStartAddress,
         LPVOID                  lpParameter,
         BOOL                    CreateSuspended,
/*DWORD*/LONG64                  dwStackSize,
         LONG64                  SizeOfStackCommit,
         LONG64                  SizeOfStackReserve,
         LPVOID                  lpBytesBuffer      ///pointer to initialized object of NtCreateThreadExBuffer
    );
    NtCreateThreadExBuffer    * ntbuffer                = NULL;
    HANDLE                      hRemoteThread           = NULL;
    HMODULE                     hNtDllModule            = NULL;
    functypeNtCreateThreadEx    funcNtCreateThreadEx    = NULL;

    ntbuffer = new NtCreateThreadExBuffer;
    memset (ntbuffer,0,sizeof(NtCreateThreadExBuffer));///fill buffer zeros
    DWORD temp1 = 0;
    DWORD temp2 = 0;

    ntbuffer->Size = sizeof(NtCreateThreadExBuffer);
    ntbuffer->Unknown1 = 0x10003;
    ntbuffer->Unknown2 = 0x8;
    ntbuffer->Unknown3 = &temp2; 
    ntbuffer->Unknown4 = 0;
    ntbuffer->Unknown5 = 0x10004;
    ntbuffer->Unknown6 = 4;
    ntbuffer->Unknown7 = &temp1; 
    ntbuffer->Unknown8 = 0;

    //Get handle for ntdll which contains NtCreateThreadEx
    hNtDllModule = GetModuleHandle( "ntdll.dll" );
    if ( hNtDllModule == NULL )
    {
        std::cout << "Cannot get module  ntdll.dll  error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return NULL;
    }   std::cout << "A 'ntdll.dll' module has got: "<< GetLastError() << "                 [OK]" << std::endl;

    funcNtCreateThreadEx = (functypeNtCreateThreadEx)GetProcAddress( hNtDllModule, "NtCreateThreadEx" );
    if ( !funcNtCreateThreadEx )
    {
        std::cout << "Cannot get procedure address  error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return NULL;
    }   std::cout << "'NtCreateThreadEx' has executed: "<< GetLastError() << "              [OK]" << std::endl;



     ///Here is problem - when in last argument i replace NULL
    funcNtCreateThreadEx( &hRemoteThread,GENERIC_EXECUTE /*GENERIC_ALL 0x1FFFFF/*Może tu jest błąd*/, NULL, hProcess, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)lpBaseAddress, lpSpace, FALSE, NULL, NULL, NULL, ntbuffer );
    std::cout << "_______________________________________ "                         << std::endl;
    std::cout << "NtCreateThreadEx' has status:         " << GetLastError()       << std::endl;
    std::cout << "hRemoteThread:                        " << hRemoteThread        << std::endl;
    std::cout << "State of handle to DLL:               " << hNtDllModule         << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Addres of prcoedure NtCreateThreadEx: " << funcNtCreateThreadEx << std::endl;
    return hRemoteThread;
}

BOOL EnableDebugPrivilege()
{
    HANDLE hToken;
    LUID luid;
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tkp;

    if(!OpenProcessToken( GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken ))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    if(!LookupPrivilegeValue( NULL, SE_DEBUG_NAME, &luid ))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    tkp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    tkp.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
    tkp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

    if(!AdjustTokenPrivileges( hToken, false, &tkp, sizeof( tkp ), NULL, NULL ))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    if(!CloseHandle( hToken ))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: You can't inject code into a process that has a higher security level than the code that is doing the injecting. That would be a huge security breach if any arbitrary process could inject code into another process that is running as an admin. Security measures like Session Isolation and Integrity Levels exist for a reason, you can't just circumvent them at will.

Comment: I thought if i will use an undocumented feature i will can skip this protection :(. What are you thnik about CreateRemoteThread(or NtCreateThreadEx) & WriteProcessMemory (inject CodeCave code of DLL, wihout LoadLibrary) and
SetWindowsHookEx to inject DLL.
Should i try do it by other undocumented functions ?
You know: NtOpenProcess, NtWriteVirtualMemory etc ?

Comment: #EDIT:Can you give me answer for first question too ?

Comment: I will say it again - you cannot circumvent the security model. Period. It does not matter which API you use. If the OS does not want an unprivileged process injecting code into a privileged process, it won't allow it. Move on.

Comment: You should take some time to learn about security

Comment: Can you provide some links to materials? I will be grateful.Is there any other way to windows you lead to privilege escalation - to take process of any higer user or system's process ? For example, to induce a crash?

Comment: You won't listen to what we tell you, so there's not much incentive for us to try to help you.

Answer (score -1):

try: zwcreatethreatex function.

```
typedef_ZwCreateThreadEx ZwCreateThreadEx = (typedef_ZwCreateThreadEx)::GetProcAddress(hNtdllDll, "ZwCreateThreadEx");
if (NULL == ZwCreateThreadEx)
{
    ShowError("GetProcAddress_ZwCreateThread");
    return FALSE;
}
```